# Create small polygons inside large polygons in SVG using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, polygons

I am very new to SVG graphics.I am trying to create multiple SVG polygons inside a svg rectangle.

I am facing challenge in creating smaller polygon inside big polygon.

My polygons are multi sided and not just triangles and rectangles. How do I get points of inner polygon , I have points of parent polygon and spacing distance between parent and child polygon

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    
  <polygon id="poly_depth1" points="60,20 100,40 100,80 60,100 20,80 20,40" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

Consider above example , I have a polygon with id poly_depth1, I want to create another polygon 10px inside this polygon.I want to create this child polygon  using plain JavaScript or D3.The polygon should retain the same shape.

Comment: What does "10px inside" mean?  That's not clear.  What have you tried?  There are many tutorials on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on the web that explain how to create SVG shapes in Javascript (with either vanilla Javascript or libraries like D3).

Comment: "10px" inside mean the gap between outer and inner polygon.I googled a lot and did not get any help from web. This might be pure geometry question.I need help with writing javascript function which will give me the x,y points of my inner polygon. Something like getInnerPolyPoints(OuterPolyPoints,depth) {}; depth is how much inside I want my inner polygon is.

Comment: For an arbitrary polygon, that is going to be extremely hard.  But if you can say that it is always going to be a hexagon, for instance, or always a regular polygon, then that would be a lot simpler.

Comment: Polygons are arbitary..both shapes and size is not fixed..but its going to be regular polygons like 3 sided,4 sided ,5 sided etc not the curved ones.I tried writing the logic but failed. I am hoping someone can help me writing that logic in javascript or any programming language is fine I will convert it to javascript.

Comment: Hey Techies ..please help...still not found answer to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code to do what you want (I believe).

For each point in the polygon, it calculates a new point that is a specified distance further in toward the centre of the polygon.

It then appends a new polygon using the set of adjusted points.

```js
// A reference to the original polygon
var poly1 = document.getElementById("poly_depth1");

// Calculate the average of the x and y coordinates.
// So we have a point inside the polygon
var poly2points = getInsidePolygon(poly1, 10);

// Create a new polygon with the adjusted points
var poly2 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
poly2.setAttribute("id", "poly_depth2");
poly2.setAttribute("points", poly2points.join(','))
poly1.ownerSVGElement.appendChild(poly2);



function getInsidePolygon(poly, distance)
{
  var points = poly.points;
  var centre = getCentrePoint(points);

  // For each polygon point, move towards the centre point by
  // 'distance' and return that point
  var result = []
  for (var i=0; i<points.numberOfItems; i++) {
    var pt = points.getItem(i);
    var adjustedPt = getPointAlongLine(pt.x, pt.y, centre.x, centre.y, distance);
    result.push(adjustedPt.x.toFixed(4));
    result.push(adjustedPt.y.toFixed(4));
  }

  return result;
}


function getCentrePoint(points)
{
  // Average all the X and Y points to get the polygon centre point
  var midX = 0, midY = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<points.numberOfItems; i++) {
    var pt = points.getItem(i);
    midX += pt.x;
    midY += pt.y;
  }
  return {
    x: midX / points.numberOfItems,
    y: midY / points.numberOfItems
  }
}


function getPointAlongLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, distance)
{
  // Return the point that is "distance" along the line from x1,y1 to x2,y2.
  var dx = x2 - x1;
  var dy = y2 - y1;
  var len = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return {
    x: x1 + dx * (distance / len),
    y: y1 + dy * (distance / len)
  }
}
```

```css
#poly_depth2 {
  fill: red;
  fill-opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<svg width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 0 120 120"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    
  <polygon id="poly_depth1" points="60,20 100,40 100,80 60,100 20,80 20,40" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The points attribute defines the x and y coordinates for each corner of the polygon. If you want smaller or bigger polygon you need to either add or subtract the distance from the x and y coordinates of the polygon.

```
<svg width="140" height="140" viewBox="0 0 120 120"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <polygon id="poly_depth1" points="60,20 100,40 100,80 60,100 20,80 20,40" fill="blue"/>
  <polygon id="poly_depth2" points="60,35 90,50 90,70 60,85 30,70 30,50" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  your "poly_depth2" is coming exactly inside "poly_depth1" . My depth1 poly's are dynamic. I need help with writing javascript function which will give me the x,y points of my inner polygon.  Something like getInnerPolyPoints(OuterPolyPoints,depth) {}; depth is how much inside I want my inner polygon is.

Comment: I might be not able to write a javascript function for you but you can try some workaround by either add or subtract the distance from the x and y coordinates of the polygon.